# Comparing an encrypted user_id stored in a cookie with the user_id stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies, sha1

in my web application, after the user loges in, the user_id gets encrypted and then stored in a cookie. However, I'm facing problems when I want to use the compare the user_id stored in the cookie with the one stored in my database.

for example,

```
$sql = "insert into tasks (title,prior,sdate,ddate,dis)
    values ('".$_GET['title']."', '".$_GET['priority']."', '".$_GET['sdate']."', '".$_GET['ddate']."','".$_GET['dis']."')
    where user_id = '". $_COOKIE['auth'] ."'
    ";
```

I am getting an error because the id stored in the cookie is different than the one stored in the database.

this is how I encrypted the user_id and stored it in the cookie

```
 $hashed_id = sha1($id);
 setcookie('auth', $hashed_id, time()+ 1209600, '/');
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the notice. However, security is not required for now.

Comment: Why not simply store the user id unencrypted in a session?

Comment: If security isn't required, then why encrypt the id?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is for a PHP class project. It is required to use only cookies.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Just part of the requirements. Major security requirements are going to be done later.

Comment: They should really teach you prepared statements with placeholder values *first* because it saves you from a ton of escaping-related trouble.

Comment: @tadman any idea how to solve that?

Comment: ...and might save you a breach because you missed/forgot to fix it later. You could generate a random token for each user that you store in the database and a cookie. That way, you can compare it straight off against the database but still haven't exposed the user id. You can also save the user ip, user agent etc hashed in the DB and in a cookie on login and compare that too.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I'm sure it's not super important here, but it's good to note that SHA1 is considered junk these days because it's been compromised. Use SHA2-256 or better. It's also worth noting that your "hash" here is worthless because it's super obvious what you're hashing, there's no salt. `356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab` is the SHA1 hash of `"1"` and it's trivial to spin through all possible numbers to see which one matches.

Comment: As for prepared statements: These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.